# Execl Data Auto express

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel workbook that contains macros, I wanted to auto update the data that it contains. Right now I have to manually copy paste the data into the workbook, because the data is coming from a different excel worksheet. Is there a way I can auto update the data that is from a worksheet located on a sharepoint site online and is updated every night.

Answer (score 0):

You've left a lot to be considered such as; will the location of the data that you want to copy be the same each time? If not will the range be named?  Will the size of the range be the same every time?

I think you're probably best off writing your update code in the Workbook_Open() event

To get you started, you can open the workbook by using

`Dim wbUpdateFromMe As Workbook
 wbUpdateFromMe = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFullPathIncludingFileNameAndExtention)`

The path should look something like \\sharepoint.mysharepointsitename.com\locationonsp\updatefromme.xlm

then use

`wbUpdateFromMe.sheets("FromSheetName").Range("FromRangeName").copy  Destination:=Thisworkbook.sheets("ToSheetName").Range("ToRangeName")`

to copy and paste, but you may want to do some clearing out of old data first.